# Add "How do I get a job doing XXXXX" to FAQ "don't ask"

Tags: discussion, faq-content

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/4398/2322) made me realize the [FAQ](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq) doesn't specifically reference not asking "how do I get a job doing XXX" and variants.

I recommend we add an additional question to the FAQ in the format of:

- "How do I get a job doing...?"

  - General questions about how to find jobs in specific industries or having particular characteristics are difficult to answer and invites discussion and lists of answers.

Questions like this are incredibly difficult to not turn into "list for me resources to do $(XXXXX)" types of questions.

---

You could update the following

- "Please review my resume/CV"

to be

"Please review my resume/CV or help me get/find a job"

Comment: Arg, I really figured this would be covered by the "how do I be a..." section, I guess it isn't (explicitly). Is there some way we could worm that definition into the existing questions? I'd like to prevent the FAQ from getting any longer than necessary and it seems very related to what's in there...

Comment: @Rarity you could potentially do this in my update